# SQL keep two decimal places for integers after converting cent into dollar

Tags: sql, plsql

I am trying convert number values stored in the database as cents into dollar and keep 2 decimal places.

The following code will work only if v_cent/100.00 is NOT integer

```
  SELECT CAST(ROUND(v_cent/100.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(8,2)) FROM DUAL;
```

If v_cent = 20000 then the result is 200.

How could I reserve 2 decimal places even if the result is integer?

Comment: The 2 decimal places are in place. They are not shown because there is nothing there, if the number is whole. When you show it, you can format it. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i16209

Answer (score 0):

Use `to_char()`, say to convert this to an output format with two decimal places:

```
select to_char(v_cent / 100.0, 'FM999999.99')
from dual;
```

As for your formulation it is doing the right thing.  The only issue is that the decimal points are not printed out by default.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The result is "200." using your statement. hmm, interesting...

Comment: @Dorisacat use 'FM999990.00'  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#i34570

Comment: @Mottor Oh got it. Now I understand the implication behind 0 and 9. Thanks a lot!